# Sketching the four subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

[The four Subspaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G377C.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G377C.png)For an arbitrary  matrix C how does one produce the four subspaces i.e  rectangles for an a) invertible matrix and b) a zero matrix?

Comment: Subspaces aren't rectangles...  The image is drawn in such a way simply because it is difficult to visualize infinite regions and also difficult to visualize objects and spaces in higher dimensions.  The positions of the rectangles in the image are purely artistic and have no mathematical meaning whatsoever.

Comment: Ohhhh so how to approach this question then?

Comment: As for the math behind your true question, it all comes down to the [fundamental theorem of linear algebra (the four subspaces theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra), the knowledge of what an [invertible matrix is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem) and the knowledge of what a zero matrix is.  It should be clear what the dimension of an invertible matrix's nullspace and column space are by the fact that it is an invertible matrix.  Similarly so for a zero matrix.

Comment: Yes dimension is three for invertible and the zero matrix is just a point in the space.Dimension of the null space of an invertible is 3.I know this but don't know how to construct the rectangles.I need to construct rectangles for this question.

Comment: Ohhh so I basically have a point for zero matrix then

Comment: And for the invertible I have no null space just the row and the column space

Comment: "*I need to construct rectangles*"  There are no rectangles to construct...  "*Dimension is three for invertible*"  Why three?  I thought you were talking about an arbitrary invertible matrix of unknown size and shape, where does $3$ come from?  Also, which dimension?  There are four different dimensions that are interesting and needing to be talked about: dimension of nullspace, dimension of column space, dimension of row space, and of left nullspace.  "*dimension of the null space of an invertible is 3*"  No, the nullity (dimension of nullspace) of an invertible matrix is *always* zero.

Comment: ohhh I am just confused.I get it no rectangles to construct.SO arbitrary matrix has unknown size and shape I didn't know that.

Comment: So basically everything is zero..Ahhh I am so confused.

Comment: dimension of column space  for an invertible matrix will be m .

Comment: dimension of the row space would be n and the null space will be zero and left null space is zero also

Comment: So I get all the information so how do I sketch it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix of size $n\times n$ representing a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$.

[It is well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem) that an invertible matrix is of "full rank" and so the dimension of the column space of $A$ is $n$ as well as the dimension of the row space of $A$ is $n$ while the dimension of the null space and left-null space are both $0$.

As for a zero matrix, let $O$ be a matrix of size $m\times n$ containing only zeroes representing a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$ which maps every input from the domain to the zero vector in the codomain.

It should be clear that $Ov=0$ as well as $wO=0$ for all $v,w$ where $0$ represents whichever appropriate zero vector for the situation.  As such, it should be clear that the dimension of the row space and column space of $O$ are both zero.  The dimension of the null-space and the left-null space are $n$ and $m$ respectively.

If you absolutely insist on "drawing rectangles" to visualize the spaces, whichever space is of dimension zero is representable by a single dot at the origin while the remaining fundamental subspace takes up the entirety of whichever space it was in which I personally wouldn't bother enclosing in a rectangle at all (*beyond some way to separate it from answers or figures to other questions*).

I will reiterate my first comment above that the "rectangles" pictured in your linked image are purely an artistic representation of the various fundamental subspaces in the sense that the subspaces are subsets of their parent space and don't overlap one another except at the origin and there are those elements in the parent space which might not fall into either category but rather a combination thereof.  The analogy is imperfect however as spaces and subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$ are infinite in size and unbounded and may be however many dimensions large and thus in many cases cannot be easily representable in a two-dimensional image.  Remember that a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ is always either the origin itself, a line passing through the origin, a plane passing through the origin, or a hyperplane passing through the origin, never a literal rectangle.